# Is possible to use dynamic table names in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, dynamic, oracle11g

Can I do something like it?

```
SELECT * FROM bd.images_ || '2011'
```

Because I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    x.name, x.year, w.imgblob
FROM
    bd.img_idx x,
    (SELECT imgblob FROM bd.images_ || x.year WHERE name = x.name) w
WHERE
    x.name = 'nanananana'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not with static SQL. You can use [Native Dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/11_dynam.htm) (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE), which probably suits your use case or the more complex(and powerful) DBMS_SQL package.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad design.

I speak about tables `bd.images_yyyy`. Best is to have them in a single table bd_images with a column year, **partitioned** on year.

Your query would become:

```
SELECT
    x.name, x.year, w.imgblob
FROM
    bd.img_idx x 
    JOIN bd.images w on (x.year = w.year and w.name = x.name) 
WHERE
    x.name = 'nanananana'
```

However, you can do some **dynamic ddl** in case you can't modify your database or you don't have **enterprise license**.

Create a temptable with name, year, imgblob (tmptable).

Populate it with:

```
Procedure populate_tmp (text varchar2)
begin
for r in (select x.name, x.year from bd.img_idx x where x.name= text)
loop
   execute immediate 'insert into tmptable values ('||r.name||','||r.year||',' (select w.imgblob from bd.images'||r.year||' w where w.year = '||r.year||' and w.name= '||r.name||'))';

end loop;
end;
```

and after populate('nananannaa') you can select from tmptable.

*Attention*: for not dealing with old data in tmptable you can create it as `global temporary table on commit delete`. When you commit, the data will disapear from table.

Comment: I can't modify database. And I want to avoid using stored procedures because I have to ask permission to the database administrator on every change to the procedure.

Comment: Maybe it is smarter to communicate with the dba to explain what your business needs are instead of trying to use tricks? Might be a lot easier to be able to use partitions or maybe even the good old partitioned views. Make sure to use bind variables, also when using dynamic SQL.

Comment: sure, ik_self is right. And you and your DBA have a technical boss, and he should understand what is better: DBA to do nothing and you work 4 months OR DBA work 1 day and you 3 days. It is not your choise, it is His choise (the Technical leader)

Comment: This would be possible in an ideal work situation where everyone works together. ehehhe This is not my case and each leader/manager is worried about their jobs. I thought there would be an easy way to do this but I realized it's not possible then I will use the powerful 'do...while' code to solve the problem. Thank you guys. :)

Comment: if you have an answer that fit better to your situation, you can add the answer and as I know, you can select it as accepted :)